# Access application items from other applications only through fetch_app_item?

Tags: oracle-apex, session-variables

I have several applications in an Oracle APEX 19.2 workspace that use shared authentication. In order to access enduser metadata, I want to use an application item defined as global in the master application. It seems to be configered correctly: In a slave application, I can see the correct session value in the debugger windows (Session State, View: Application Items).

But the usual replacement syntaxes do not work: I can not access the value with any of those methods:

`:VARIABLE`

`&VARIABLE.`

`apex_util.get_session_state('variable')`

The only method that is working is `apex_util.fetch_app_item('variable',[application id])` - this is cumbersome, as I would like to work with application aliases and I would need to translate the alias using the view `apex_applications`.

Is this working as intended or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Hi Thomas, did you still need help with this or did Patrick's answer work? If it worked, please accept the answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created the same application item in the slave application as well? You will also have to set it to Scope = Global. This will expose the value in the current application.

Comment: Well I did not know I need to do that, as the value was already visible in the debugger without it. Will try at work tomorrow and report again - thanks!